# Power BI - Get the Days of current Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column "Days of Month" which is just rows from 1 to 31 and a filter above with the date as you can see in the screenshot below. I want to filter this column to show me the days of each month based on the filter above.
For example if the date above is 2/2/2020 i would like to see 28 rows on my column.
I tried several solutions but i couldn't achieve this.

Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by duplicating the date table and creating a relationship to its duplicate on year and month.

1. Add a [YearMonth] column to your date table

[image: Dates table]

2. Duplicate the Dates table as Dates2

[image: Dates2 table]

3. Create a many-to-many data relationship between Dates and Dates2 on the [YearMonth] column. Set the cross filter direction to Single (Dates filters Dates2)

[image]

4. Set up your report to use a slicer or filter on Dates[Date] and display Date2[Day] in a table visual. Here is the result:

[image: result]